# Is there an Eldritch Horror variant for playing against two ancients at once?

Tags: house-rules, eldritch-horror

Has anyone tried modifying the rules of Eldritch Horror so you can play against two ancients at the same time? **How was your experience?**

***Mysteries***

- Do I solve alternating or in parallel?

***Mythos***

- Do I take a sum or average of myths cards? (Mythos Deck Composition)
- Do I buy one or two Mythos Cards?

***Doom Token***

- Greater, average or lower to start?

***Handicap combos***

- Extra Action?
- Bonus for tests?
- Acquire bonus?

Comment: At Arkham Nights 2016 there was a game held with two ancient Ones and 16 players.

Answer (score 1):

No playtesting yet, but I was thinking about such variant.
Some initial thoughts:

- I would sum up the doom of both AOs. If this total drops to 0, both AO's awaken.
- The two respective mythos decks are shuffled: First stage of 1st AO with 1st stage of 2nd AO, and so on.
- Each AO has one active mystery. "Advance the mystery" effects allow you to advance the either of these, but not both at the same time.
- When having a Research encounter, you may choose from which AO's deck you'll draw.

The biggest dilemma for me is how to treat Cultists.

Comment: Treat cultists based on the omen - blue is for one and the red/green for the other